# how to display data from two table, one to many in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have two table SQL

1. table users

   - no_kk
   - name
2. table kk

   - id
   - name_kk
   - status
   - educate
   - no_id

   in this case no_kk relation with no_id. i will display all spesific data by parameter no_kk, please help me thanks all

Answer (score 1):

```
Use join query for this.    
sample for user table:      
$this->db->select('kk.*,users.*')->join('users', 'users.no_kk = kk.no_id');
$this->db->where('kk.no_id', $no_kk);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, next time I'll aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose your query as follows

```
public function get_data($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('kk');
    $this->db->join('users','kk.no_id = users. no_kk');
    $this->db->where('kk.no_id = "$id"');
    $result_set = $this->db->get();
    if($result_set->num_rows() > 0){
       return $result_set->result();
    }else{
       return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Pass in your user id to the model and return the result set.

In the controller, while loading the view, pass in the array returned from the model.

```
public function your-controller-method(){
   $data['result'] = $this->your-model->get_data($user_id);

   $this->load->view('your-view-name',$data);
}
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: The resultset will be in an array of object formats. You can pass the array to the view and loop the array as per your requirements.

Comment: Please go through the Codeigniter documentation. It can help you. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html

Comment: Did your problem fixed??

Comment: in your post controller. i add parameter public function your-controller-method($user_id). but when i loop error

Comment: I can't guide you more than this. My code is just an example. `$user_id` is a variable that will act as a parameter to join your tables and fetch records based on your `user_id`. It is dynamic. So you have passed the user id that you want to add in the condition.

Comment: What error you are getting?? Please update your question so that I can get some clarity on how it can be solved.

Comment: are you have email

Comment: did you get result are not

Answer (score 0):

In view page you can display like this in table format or any other you like.

View page code in table format:

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $row['fieldname'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['fieldname1'];?></td>
<td>...</td>.......
</<tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read your question, you have done with getting data from two tables by using the join query, but for now, your problem is to show how to view this data in your table view. 
for this purpose, you have to create few files in different folders

in view

use the for each loop to fetch data in table view

```
<?php if (!empty($users)) 

                    {
                        foreach ($users as $user) 
                            { ?>        

                            <tr>    
                                <td>    <?php echo $user['name'] ?>     </td>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>      
                        </tr>   
                    <?php
                     }
                     }  

                    ?>
```

and in controller file  add view function

```
public function view()
    {
                $this->load->model('uModel');

                $data['users']= $this->uModel->All();

                $this->load->view('list' , $data);  
    }
```

and in model file add this function

```
    public function All()                   
    {
        return $users = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();
    }
```

it will definitely help you out 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys but in this case i will fetch data from my relation tabel is a tabel kk. I'm still confused for looping related data in kk tables. for example one user has 4 kk_name and kk_status how to display only 4 data, because there is very much data in the kk table. Thanks all